# BlueImp File Upload Widget for Yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, blueimp

Can anyone provide manuals for this yii2 plugin use?

I have installed it but have not been able to find the options it accepts, for example: Right after an image is uploaded, the thumbnail displayed is in full size (bigger than the page width). How to resize that?

Thank you.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBbUX.png)